# How to find difference between images using a specific formula in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to find the difference between two consecutive images using this formula,

```
difference = 1/(64 * 64) summation(i=1 to 64) summation(j=1 to 64)  [SI(i, j, k) − SI(i, j, k + 1)]
```

where `SI(i j k)` is an image and `SI (i j k+1)` is next images. the ans of the above difference should be a single value.

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: the two images in my program are 64 x 64 gray images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
mean(mean((SI(:, :, k)-SI(:,:,k+1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sum.html).

1. Assuming `SI` has size 64 x 64 x something.

   ```
   sum(sum(SI(:,:,k)-SI(:,:,k+1)))/64^2
   ```
2. If you have two separate 64x64 arrays, say `SI1` and `SI2`:

   ```
   sum(sum(SI1-SI2))/64^2
   ```

   or, probably faster,

   ```
   sum(SI1(:)-SI2(:))/64^2
   ```

Comment: thanks for the help. But i just tested it and it is not working. size is 64 x 64